# Powershell can't see module or function despite it being installed

Tags: powershell

Slightly stumped, when I check to see if my powershell module is installed:

```
(Get-InstalledModule MyModule).InstalledLocation
```

*`C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MyModule\1.0.7`*

All good, but running a public function on that module fails to find the function. Worse still, I can't even import it:

```
Import-Module -Name MyModule -Force
```

*`The specified module 'MyModule ' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.`*

That's doesn't make any sense from my perspective. It's not only my PC either, we're seeing multiple employees with the problem. Has anyone hit this before? Reopening powershell windows and restarting PCs etc achieves nothing.

Uninstall-Module -Name MyModule achieves absolutely nothing also.

*$env:PSModulePath* shows the path correctly configured.

Comment: Perhaps something edited/overwrote/corrupted the module manifest? `Test-ModuleManifest 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MyModule\1.0.7\MyModule.psd1'`

Comment: Great shout, turns out the version defined in my .psd1 didn't match the directory version

Comment: There you go :) For future reference `Import-Module modulename -Verbose` is also a good place to start